# Sublime Text 3 LaTeXTools plugin won't compile on Debian

Tags: latex, sublimetext, sublimetext3, latexmk

When doing Ctrl+B on SublimeText3, the following error is output:

```
[Compiling first.tex]

TraditionalBuilder: Invoking latexmk... 

COULD NOT COMPILE!

Attempted command:latexmk -cd -e $pdflatex='pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S %O' -f -pdf first.tex
Build engine: Traditional Builder
```

Running the exact same command compiles a pdf file just fine.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384330/sublime-text-3-latextools-plugin-wont-compile-on-ubuntu) does not solve the problem, as I've

- Removed spaces around "="
- Done a "Reconfigure LaTeXTools and migrate settings".
- Made sure pdflatex is installed.
- Made sure the path for texpath is correct.

Comment: This is an almost word-for-word duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384330/sublime-text-3-latextools-plugin-wont-compile-on-ubuntu). Please follow the instructions in the answer there, and [edit] your question if it still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @MattDMo Yes, I saw that question, but mine is different (I can run the exact same command on the command line) and the answer there does not solve my issue (removing spaces around "=", reconfiguring LaTeXTools, and changing paths).

Comment: OK, that's good to know, and thanks for the edit to your question. I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your command runs on terminal then most likely there is an issue either with the path or with the command itself (in the file). There has been some update to the README file by the developer:

> - some distros do *not* want a space before and after the `=` in `$pdflatex = %E`. But some *do* want the space there (sigh!)
> - sometimes `latexmk` is not on the `PATH`, or the path is not correctly picked up by ST. In this case, instead of `"latexmk"`, use `"/usr/bin/latexmk"` or wherever `latexmk` is in your system.
> - some distros require quoting the `$pdflatex` assignment, as in `"$pdflatex = \"'%E -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S %O'\""`

So it might take a while but you'll find it eventually in the settings or the traditionalbuilder.py file.
Also when I tried putting /usr/bin/latexmk, latex did not produce the correct pdf (I checked it with few changes and it just opened the old pdf) but in your case it might work.
Also, at least in Arch Linux I can't run sublime with sublime-text but instead with subl so I changed that too in the settings (I don't know if it actually matters) and I needed to change the permissions for the files because user-run sublime could not access my settings files!

Comment: Thanks! What did the trick for me was to use an explicit path to latexmk.